# Trigger not calling other trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Using SQL-server.

I have 2 tables and 2 update triggers.

1st trigger gets called on an update to table A.
2nd trigger gets called on an update to table B.

Both triggers fire fine when updating the tables individually

**Here's the issue:**
the trigger for table A forces on update to table B. At this time, the 2nd trigger never fires. I'm not sure why not? But if I make a change to table B manually (not through the trigger), the 2nd trigger does fire.

**My set up:**
I'm using cursors as I want row level triggers. I'm also using the keyword 'FOR' for before update transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you need to configure the behavior of nested triggers:

[Configure the nested triggers Server Configuration Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178101.aspx)

> When nested triggers is set to 0, AFTER triggers cannot cascade. When nested triggers is set to 1 (the default), AFTER triggers can cascade to as many as 32 levels. INSTEAD OF triggers can be nested regardless of the setting of this option.

Comment: Yes, it's on the quoted text. This is the most normal cause. I'm exposing the main reason for this behavior (not the only possible one). Let's see if this solves the OP problem

Comment: Yes I had cascade off, this solved the problem. Will accept when able to